# deploy web service on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, service, web, war

I have problem when I try to run my service after deploy it on tomcat, after deploy my war file on tomcat, I got the war and its unzip on tomcat/webapp, but I can't see it on the Applications list, and when I try to access to my application manually:

localhost:8080/Test myWS/   >> I got HTTP 404 error

when I checked the log file I found the following:

```
WARNING: Error while removing context [/Test myWS]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1248)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1219)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:608)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inenter code herevoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

can you please help me ? thanks

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using? [Bug 51162](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51162), which was fixed in v6.0.33, seems very similar to your problem.

Comment: time to upgrade tomcat!

Comment: I see no evidence of that bug in the [Tomcat 7 changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) so I'd recommend trying it :-)

Comment: Is that the full stack trace ? It does not include the underlying root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried deploying a webapp with a space in its name - can you change the name to not have a space or change the URL you test to localhost:8080/Test+myWS or localhost:8080/Test%20myWS ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, I have solved the problem, It was because of TOMCAT version ans the name of the war file with spaces.

thanks again :)